# How to get the ERc20 token price

Tags: erc-20

how to get the erc20 token price like in chain link from this code i am getting the token price of price feed address but How to get my own erc20 token price from chainlink

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract TokenPriceConsumer {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
     int public tokenPriceUSD;

    constructor(address _oracleAddress) {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_oracleAddress);
        tokenPriceUSD = 50;
 
    }
  function getETHPrice() public view returns(int) {
        (, int price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return (price / 10**8);
    }
     function facuTokenPriceInETH() public view returns(int) {
        int ethPrice = getETHPrice();
        return tokenPriceUSD / ethPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: chainlink provides the prices of many known tokens https://data.chain.link/ . is your token one of them?

Comment: No can I list my token there

Comment: sorry i have no answer, I think entities pay for chainlink to provide these data